# Disk space is full because of sql server log file

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

I have a database that's data file and log file default set in c drive.
Now I found just because of log file my server's c drive is almost full.
Can I change the log file and move the log file in different drives?

Comment: It's considered best practice to not have any of your data files on the C drive. Ideally the C drive should be for the OS only (usually windows) and you store your data files elsewhere. So yes, you can move your log files off the C drive. There's a few ways of doing it. What have you researched before asking the question?

Comment: @RichBenner its production server thts why my worry is there to move data files amd log files

Comment: you'd be best posting this to dba.stackexchange.com. Explain that you need to move the log file on a production database and i'm sure you'll get some further assistance.